# tbb serial task faster than parallel

Tags: tbb

I created serial task for counting determinant:

```
class serialTask : public task {
matrix m;
int *determinant;
serialTask(matrix m_, int* sum) : m(m_), determinant(sum) {}
task* execute()
{
    *determinant = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m.get_size(); i++)
    {
        int cur_elem = m.get_values()[0][i];
        if (m.get_size() == 1)
        {
            *determinant += cur_elem;
        }
        else
        {
            int x;
            matrix new_m = m.cut_matrix(0, i);
            serialTask& task = *new(allocate_child()) serialTask(new_m, &x);
            set_ref_count(2);
            spawn_and_wait_for_all(task);
            int step = 2 + i;
            *determinant += cur_elem * pow(-1, step) * x;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

};

...and parallel task:

```
class parallelTask : public task {
matrix m;
int *determinant;
int* results;
parallelTask(matrix mat, int* sum) : m(mat), determinant(sum), results(new int[m.get_size()]) {}
task* execute()
{
    task_list tasks;
    int *elems = new int[m.get_size()];
    if (m.get_size() == 1)
    {
        *determinant = m.get_values()[0][0];
    }
    else
    {
        *determinant = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m.get_size(); i++)
        {
            elems[i] = m.get_values()[0][i];
            matrix new_m = m.cut_matrix(0, i);
            tasks.push_back(*new(allocate_child()) parallelTask(new_m, &results[i]));
        }
        set_ref_count(m.get_size() + 1);
        spawn_and_wait_for_all(tasks);
        for (int j = 0; j < m.get_size(); j++)
        {
            int step = 1 + j + 1;
            *determinant += elems[j] * pow(-1, step) * results[j];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

};

Parallel task should work faster than serial for big matrix, and slower for small one. But situation is opposite: serial task is much faster than parallel for big matrix.

Could someone tell me where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "CutOff" parameter as described in [TBB Fibonacci example](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/hh_goto.htm?index.htm#tbb_userguide/Simple_Example_Fibonacci_Numbers.html) so that the overhead involved in order to get the work done in parallel does not prevail (or even take less than 5-10%, as recommended) the work in the task. Otherwise, the use of the parallel version of the algorithms is not justified.